# Is it possible to style a java application?

Tags: java, look-and-feel

I'm making a java application that is very large and I am going about stupid ways to uneffectively style windows, buttons, inputs, etc. is there a way I could universally adjust the style of all components like making my own look and feel.

Comment: swing or fx? Fx supports css styles that are pretty simple.

Comment: Like [JGoodies Looks](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/looks/)?

Comment: use some IDE like NetBeans,etc. and then custom adjust your Swing items!

Comment: For Swing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/, For JavaFX: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/css_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using swing, I would recommend [JWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) if you want to customize border, maximize, minimize, close buttons of the window of your application.